# How to include the contents of a stylesheet in <style>?

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF 2.0 page that uses this:

```
<h:head>
<h:outputStylesheet name="screen.css" library="css" />
</h:head>
```

Which very nicely generates this HTML:

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
    href="/myapp/javax.faces.resource/screen.css.jsf?ln=css" />
</head>
```

This is great when the page is being viewed in a browser.  However, I want to use this stylesheet embedded in an HTML page that will be emailed to the user.  I don't want their email client to load the stylesheet from the server.  I want the document emailed to them to be self-sufficient and not be influenced by changes in (or even the absence of) the stylesheet on the website.

I want the HTML output to be like this:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    ...contents of screen.css here...
</style>
</head>
```

I tried to achieve that by using this:

```
<h:head>
<style type="text/css">
<ui:include src="/resources/css/screen.css"></ui:include>
</style>
</h:head>
```

But I received this error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /resources/css/screen.css: 
Error Traced[line: 1] Content is not allowed in prolog.
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:325)
```

How can I get the contents of the stylesheet to appear in the head of the document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with standard JSF components.

The JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has an [`<o:resourceInclude>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/resourceInclude) for the very purpose of including the raw output of non-JSF webapp resources in a JSF page.

```
<h:head>
    <style type="text/css">
        <o:resourceInclude path="/resources/css/screen.css" />
    </style>
</h:head>
```

Note that this doesn't support resource localization and versioning, nor evaluate EL expressions in CSS files like as `<h:outputStylesheet>` would do.

Comment: Thanks, @BalusC.  I'd rather avoid adding another library to my project just to get this feature, though.  Do you have any other ideas?  If it helps, my project also uses RichFaces.  I don't know if that library has any features that could help me.  Thanks for rephrasing my question, too!

Comment: OmniFaces is open source. Just create same component yourself based on its source. RichFaces has nothing like that, it's targeted on pure UI components only, not on general utilities. OmniFaces is rather unique in that.